# retrieve datacontext of treeviewitem from child xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, datacontext

I have a DataBound treeview, from which the treeviewitems are created/displayed and feature a context menu. This is working correctly. I am then trying to use a custom menuitem class so that the datacontext of the treeviewitem can be retrieved through the commands fired from the contextmenu. Sorry if this is confusing. I may be going the wrong way about doing this.

Here is my xaml.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Pipeline_General.Custom_Controls.ProjectTree"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:pm="clr-namespace:Pipeline_General"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         DataContext = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TreeView Name="StructureTree" Background="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.defaultBG}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu Background="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.defaultBG}" Foreground="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.gray}">
                            <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Add Episode.." 
                                    Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                      Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.AddEpCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                            <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Add Sequence.." 
                                      Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                      Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.AddSeqCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                            <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Add Scene.." 
                                        Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                      Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.AddScCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pm:ProjectRoot}" ItemsSource="{Binding Episodes}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Foreground="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.pink}"
                           FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContextMenu Background="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.defaultBG}" Foreground="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.gray}">
                                    <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Add Sequence.."  
                                     Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                     Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.AddSeqCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                                    <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Add Scene.."
                                      Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                      Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.AddScCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                                    <Separator Height="15" Margin="20,0"/>
                                    <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Cut" 
                                    Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                    Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.CutCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                                    <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Un-Cut" 
                                    Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                    Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.UnCutCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>


                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pm:Episode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Sequences}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" Foreground="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.yellow}"
                                           FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="14"/>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
                                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ContextMenu Background="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.defaultBG}" Foreground="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.gray}">
                                            <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Add Scene.." 
                                             Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                             Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.AddScCommand}" 
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                            Margin="20,0"/>
                                            <Separator Height="15" Margin="20,0"/>
                                            <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Cut" 
                                            Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                            Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.CutCommand}" 
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                            Margin="20,0"/>
                                            <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Un-Cut" 
                                             Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                            Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.UnCutCommand}" 
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                             Margin="20,0"/>
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pm:Sequence}" ItemsSource="{Binding Scenes}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" Foreground="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.yellow}"
                                           FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="14"/>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ContextMenu Background="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.defaultBG}" Foreground="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.gray}">
                                                    <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Cut" 
                                                        Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                                        Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.CutCommand}" 
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                                        Margin="20,0"/>
                                                    <pm:ProjectTreeMenuItem Header="Un-Cut" 
                                                         Element="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                                                        Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.UnCutCommand}" 
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                                         Margin="20,0"/>
                                                </ContextMenu>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

and my custom menu item class and commands.

```
public static class MyCommands
{
    static MyCommands()
    {
        AddEpCommand = new SimpleDelegateCommand(p =>
        {
            var menuItem = p as ProjectTreeMenuItem;
            var Element = menuItem.Element as ProjectElement;
            Console.WriteLine(Element.Key);
            Console.WriteLine("EP");
        });

        AddSeqCommand = new SimpleDelegateCommand(p =>
        {
            var menuItem = p as ProjectTreeMenuItem;
            var Element = menuItem.Element as ProjectElement;
            Console.WriteLine(Element.Key);
            Console.WriteLine("SEQ");
        });

        AddScCommand = new SimpleDelegateCommand(p =>
        {
            var menuItem = p as ProjectTreeMenuItem;
            var Element = menuItem.Element as ProjectElement;
            Console.WriteLine(Element.Key);
            Console.WriteLine("SC");
        });

        CutCommand = new SimpleDelegateCommand(p =>
        {
            var menuItem = p as ProjectTreeMenuItem;
            var Element = menuItem.Element as ProjectElement;
            Console.WriteLine(Element.Key);
            Console.WriteLine("SC");
        });

        UnCutCommand = new SimpleDelegateCommand(p =>
        {
            var menuItem = p as ProjectTreeMenuItem;
            var Element = menuItem.Element as ProjectElement;
            Console.WriteLine(Element.Key);
            Console.WriteLine("SC");
        });
    }

    public static ICommand AddEpCommand { get; set; }
    public static ICommand AddSeqCommand { get; set; }
    public static ICommand AddScCommand { get; set; }
    public static ICommand CutCommand { get; set; }
    public static ICommand UnCutCommand { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleDelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public SimpleDelegateCommand(Action<object> executeAction)
    {
        _executeAction = executeAction;
    }

    private Action<object> _executeAction;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeAction(parameter);
    }
}

public class ProjectTreeMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    #region Element (DependencyProperty)
    public ProjectElement Element
    {
        get { return (ProjectElement)GetValue(ElementProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ElementProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Element", typeof(ProjectElement), typeof(ProjectTreeMenuItem),
          new PropertyMetadata { PropertyChangedCallback = ElementChanged });
    private static void ElementChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectTreeMenuItem so = d as ProjectTreeMenuItem;
        if (so != null && e.NewValue != null)
        {
            so.Element = (ProjectElement)e.NewValue;
            Console.WriteLine("HERE " + so.Element.Title);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public ProjectTreeMenuItem()
        :base()
    {

    }
}
```

The projectElement class ( which im using in hundreds of other places in the project ) has a String Key, String Title attribute which is working fine elsewhere. Im pretty sure my issues lies in setting the Element Property through the xaml via the datacontext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.. I used the command property of the menuitem and used it to send back the datacontext directly instead of using a dependency property on a custom menu item class.

The larger issue was that i was trying to use find the ancestor from the visualtree, which in a contextmenu doesnt work, and i think also because i was within a hierachialdatatemplate it wouldnt work anyway.

the following does the trick though.

```
                          <ContextMenu Background="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.defaultBG}" Foreground="{x:Static pm:myBrushes.gray}"
                                     DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Add Episode.." 
                                      Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.AddEpCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Add Sequence.." 
                                      Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.AddSeqCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Add Scene.." 
                                      Command="{x:Static pm:MyCommands.AddScCommand}" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}"
                                      Margin="20,0"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
```